# SQL Server Add a column that holds the same random number for every 48 records

Tags: sql, ssms-2016

I want to add a random invoice number plus the current date for every 48 records.  I am sorting by a column called Billing code.  I want to insert the random number plus the current date into a column called "Invoice_Number".

Below is an example of what I am trying to do:

[Example Random Invoice Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeE9T.jpg)
In the image example, notice how the "Invoice Number" changes after 48 records.

This is not the actual code that I am using but I just wanted to give you an idea on what I am trying to achieve.  The column for **' ' AS INVOICE_NUMBER** is where I would like the SQL statement to insert a random number plus the current date.

```
    SELECT
       RECORD_ID,
       NAME,
       BILLING_CODE,
       '' AS INVOICE_NUMBER
    FROM BILLING_TABLE
    ORDER BY BILLING_CODE DESC
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: You might consider using sequences for random numbers that have some logic to them.  https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/sequences.php

Comment: Random will add some complexity.  Perhaps you just want unique numbers with no business value.  I suggest you use Row_Number and Modulus 48, it should not be too hard.  If you have trouble getting it to work you can update your question with what you tried.

Comment: What are the requirements for this "random" number? in your sample image, they're all 4 digits long and sequentially assigned. I'm assuming the sequential assignment isn't a requirement since that's quite far from random. Are multiple groups allowed to be assigned the *same* random number? If not, and if e.g. 4 digits is a requirement, what should happen if there are more groups than there are 4 digit numbers?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  The image is just a sample.  It could be any random number of 9 digits long.   I was just providing an example.  The sequential is not necessary and multiple groups is not applicable.  I am seeking a random number that repeats every 48 rows.

Comment: @JoeC I'll try the row_number.  Thank you.